# export XML from excel and vice versa when a tag have multiple values in a single record

Tags: xml

I wan to export XML from an Excel file but thing is that one of tag has multiple values for a single record. I am pasting an example how my XML should look like. If you look there is a tag **"ModuleInstance"** has multiple values for a **First and Second**  record also this tag is not mandatory for every record
I want to know How can I make XML from Excel and vice versa. It is important for me to be able to covert XML back to Excel file. I have XSD file too if that is of any help in this case.
Its a student record, one record can have around 40-50 tags, and number of record can be 6000 - 7000
and unfortunately I do not have a background in coding :(

thanks in advance

```
<DataFutures>
  <Student>
    <SID>123456</SID>
    <BIRTHDTE>1940-03-29</BIRTHDTE>
    <ETHNIC>120</ETHNIC>
    <FNAMES>Stu1 first name</FNAMES>
    <GENDERID>01</GENDERID>
    <NATION>IT</NATION>
    <OWNSTU>123456</OWNSTU>
    <RELIGION>22</RELIGION>
    <SEXID>11</SEXID>
    <SEXORT>12</SEXORT>
    <SSN>DDDD12345678T</SSN>
    <SURNAME>Stu1 last name</SURNAME>
    <TTACCOM>04</TTACCOM>
    <TTPCODE>N18 1HP</TTPCODE>
    <Disability>
      <DISABILITY>95</DISABILITY>
    </Disability>
    <Engagement>
      <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
      <ENGEXPECTEDENDDATE>2023-06-23</ENGEXPECTEDENDDATE>
      <ENGSTARTDATE>2022-09-26</ENGSTARTDATE>
      <FEEELIG>01</FEEELIG>
      <EntryProfile>
        <HIGHESTQOE>I0000</HIGHESTQOE>
        <PERMADDCOUNTRY>XF</PERMADDCOUNTRY>
        <PERMADDPOSTCODE>N18 1HP</PERMADDPOSTCODE>
        <PREVIOUSPROVIDER>12345678</PREVIOUSPROVIDER>
        <EntryQualificationAward>
          <ENTRYQUALAWARDID>1</ENTRYQUALAWARDID>
          <ENTRYQUALAWARDRESULT>0001</ENTRYQUALAWARDRESULT>
          <QUALTYPEID>19</QUALTYPEID>
          <EntryQualificationSubject>
            <SUBJECTID>03P</SUBJECTID>
          </EntryQualificationSubject>
        </EntryQualificationAward>
      </EntryProfile>
      <Leaver>
        <ENGENDDATE>2022-10-28</ENGENDDATE>
        <RSNENGEND>11</RSNENGEND>
      </Leaver>
      <QualificationAwarded>
        <QUALAWARDID>1</QUALAWARDID>
        <QUALAWARDRESULT>0001</QUALAWARDRESULT>
        <QUALID>asd</QUALID>
      </QualificationAwarded>
      <StudentAccreditationAim>
        <STUACCID>05804</STUACCID>
      </StudentAccreditationAim>
      <StudentCourseSession>
        <SCSESSIONID>2323234</SCSESSIONID>
        <COURSEID>DET</COURSEID>
        <INTERCALATION>01</INTERCALATION>
        <INVOICEFEEAMOUNT>6000</INVOICEFEEAMOUNT>
        <INVOICEHESAID>5053</INVOICEHESAID>
        <RSNSCSEND>01</RSNSCSEND>
        <SCSENDDATE>2023-10-03</SCSENDDATE>
        <SCSFEEAMOUNT>6000</SCSFEEAMOUNT>
        <SCSMODE>01</SCSMODE>
        <SCSSTARTDATE>2022-09-26</SCSSTARTDATE>
        <SESSIONYEARID>2323234</SESSIONYEARID>
        <YEARPRG>1</YEARPRG>
        <ModuleInstance>
          <MODINSTID>1</MODINSTID>
          <MODID>123</MODID>
          <MODINSTSTARTDATE>2023-11-01</MODINSTSTARTDATE>
        </ModuleInstance>
        <ModuleInstance>
          <MODINSTID>2</MODINSTID>
          <MODID>234</MODID>
          <MODINSTSTARTDATE>2023-12-01</MODINSTSTARTDATE>
        </ModuleInstance>
        <ModuleInstance>
          <MODINSTID>3</MODINSTID>
          <MODID>345</MODID>
          <MODINSTSTARTDATE>2024-01-01</MODINSTSTARTDATE>
        </ModuleInstance>
        <ReferencePeriodStudentLoad>
          <REFPERIOD>01</REFPERIOD>
          <YEAR>2022</YEAR>
          <RPSTULOAD>100</RPSTULOAD>
        </ReferencePeriodStudentLoad>
        <SessionStatus>
          <STATUSVALIDFROM>2023-09-28</STATUSVALIDFROM>
          <STATUSCHANGEDTO>02</STATUSCHANGEDTO>
        </SessionStatus>
        <StudyLocation>
          <STUDYLOCID>A</STUDYLOCID>
          <STUDYPROPORTION>100</STUDYPROPORTION>
          <VENUEID>A</VENUEID>
        </StudyLocation>
      </StudentCourseSession>
    </Engagement>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <SID>3456789</SID>
    <BIRTHDTE>1935-07-25</BIRTHDTE>
    <ETHNIC>160</ETHNIC>
    <FNAMES>Marey</FNAMES>
    <GENDERID>01</GENDERID>
    <NATION>GB</NATION>
    <RELIGION>22</RELIGION>
    <SEXID>10</SEXID>
    <SEXORT>12</SEXORT>
    <SURNAME>Shaddam</SURNAME>
    <TTACCOM>05</TTACCOM>
    <TTPCODE>RM1 8RQ</TTPCODE>
    <Disability>
      <DISABILITY>95</DISABILITY>
    </Disability>
    <Engagement>
      <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
      <ENGEXPECTEDENDDATE>2023-06-23</ENGEXPECTEDENDDATE>
      <ENGSTARTDATE>2022-09-26</ENGSTARTDATE>
      <FEEELIG>01</FEEELIG>
      <EntryProfile>
        <HIGHESTQOE>I0000</HIGHESTQOE>
        <PERMADDCOUNTRY>XF</PERMADDCOUNTRY>
        <PERMADDPOSTCODE>RM10 8RQ</PERMADDPOSTCODE>
      </EntryProfile>
      <Leaver>
        <ENGENDDATE>2022-10-29</ENGENDDATE>
        <RSNENGEND>11</RSNENGEND>
      </Leaver>
      <StudentCourseSession>
        <SCSESSIONID>456ert</SCSESSIONID>
        <COURSEID>DET</COURSEID>
        <INVOICEFEEAMOUNT>6000</INVOICEFEEAMOUNT>
        <PREPFLAG>03</PREPFLAG>
        <RSNSCSEND>01</RSNSCSEND>
        <SCSENDDATE>2022-10-29</SCSENDDATE>
        <SCSMODE>01</SCSMODE>
        <SCSSTARTDATE>1936-02-26</SCSSTARTDATE>
        <SESSIONYEARID>sdefgh</SESSIONYEARID>
        <YEARPRG>1</YEARPRG>
        <ModuleInstance>
          <MODINSTID>1</MODINSTID>
          <MODID>123</MODID>
          <MODINSTSTARTDATE>2023-11-01</MODINSTSTARTDATE>
        </ModuleInstance>
        <ModuleInstance>
          <MODINSTID>2</MODINSTID>
          <MODID>234</MODID>
          <MODINSTSTARTDATE>2023-12-01</MODINSTSTARTDATE>
        </ModuleInstance>
        <ModuleInstance>
          <MODINSTID>3</MODINSTID>
          <MODID>345</MODID>
          <MODINSTSTARTDATE>2024-01-01</MODINSTSTARTDATE>
        </ModuleInstance>
        <ReferencePeriodStudentLoad>
          <REFPERIOD>01</REFPERIOD>
          <YEAR>2022</YEAR>
          <RPSTULOAD>100</RPSTULOAD>
        </ReferencePeriodStudentLoad>
        <SessionStatus>
          <STATUSVALIDFROM>2023-09-28</STATUSVALIDFROM>
          <STATUSCHANGEDTO>02</STATUSCHANGEDTO>
        </SessionStatus>
        <StudyLocation>
          <STUDYLOCID>A</STUDYLOCID>
          <STUDYPROPORTION>100</STUDYPROPORTION>
          <VENUEID>A</VENUEID>
        </StudyLocation>
      </StudentCourseSession>
    </Engagement>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <SID>45234789</SID>
    <BIRTHDTE>1927-02-06</BIRTHDTE>
    <ETHNIC>100</ETHNIC>
    <FNAMES>Abd</FNAMES>
    <GENDERID>01</GENDERID>
    <NATION>GB</NATION>
    <RELIGION>31</RELIGION>
    <SEXID>11</SEXID>
    <SEXORT>12</SEXORT>
    <SURNAME>Gofuri</SURNAME>
    <TTACCOM>05</TTACCOM>
    <TTPCODE>E1 8UT</TTPCODE>
    <Disability>
      <DISABILITY>95</DISABILITY>
    </Disability>
    <Engagement>
      <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
      <ENGEXPECTEDENDDATE>2023-06-23</ENGEXPECTEDENDDATE>
      <ENGSTARTDATE>2022-09-26</ENGSTARTDATE>
      <FEEELIG>01</FEEELIG>
      <EntryProfile>
        <HIGHESTQOE>I0000</HIGHESTQOE>
        <PERMADDCOUNTRY>XF</PERMADDCOUNTRY>
        <PERMADDPOSTCODE>E1 4JT</PERMADDPOSTCODE>
      </EntryProfile>
      <Leaver>
        <ENGENDDATE>2022-10-30</ENGENDDATE>
        <RSNENGEND>11</RSNENGEND>
      </Leaver>
      <StudentCourseSession>
        <SCSESSIONID>qwe34</SCSESSIONID>
        <COURSEID>DET</COURSEID>
        <INVOICEFEEAMOUNT>6000</INVOICEFEEAMOUNT>
        <RSNSCSEND>01</RSNSCSEND>
        <SCSEXPECTEDENDDATE>2023-06-23</SCSEXPECTEDENDDATE>
        <SCSMODE>01</SCSMODE>
        <SCSSTARTDATE>2022-09-26</SCSSTARTDATE>
        <SESSIONYEARID>456sdf</SESSIONYEARID>
        <YEARPRG>1</YEARPRG>
        <ReferencePeriodStudentLoad>
          <REFPERIOD>01</REFPERIOD>
          <YEAR>2022</YEAR>
          <RPSTULOAD>100</RPSTULOAD>
        </ReferencePeriodStudentLoad>
        <StudyLocation>
          <STUDYLOCID>A</STUDYLOCID>
          <STUDYPROPORTION>100</STUDYPROPORTION>
          <VENUEID>A</VENUEID>
        </StudyLocation>
      </StudentCourseSession>
    </Engagement>
  </Student>
  <Student>
    <SID>2210061</SID>
    <BIRTHDTE>1963-12-25</BIRTHDTE>
    <ETHNIC>160</ETHNIC>
    <FNAMES>Johng</FNAMES>
    <GENDERID>01</GENDERID>
    <NATION>GB</NATION>
    <RELIGION>22</RELIGION>
    <SEXID>11</SEXID>
    <SEXORT>12</SEXORT>
    <SURNAME>Irodial</SURNAME>
    <TTACCOM>07</TTACCOM>
    <TTPCODE>N17 9HQ</TTPCODE>
    <Disability>
      <DISABILITY>95</DISABILITY>
    </Disability>
    <Engagement>
      <NUMHUS>1</NUMHUS>
      <ENGEXPECTEDENDDATE>2023-06-23</ENGEXPECTEDENDDATE>
      <ENGSTARTDATE>2022-09-26</ENGSTARTDATE>
      <FEEELIG>01</FEEELIG>
      <EntryProfile>
        <HIGHESTQOE>J0003</HIGHESTQOE>
        <PERMADDCOUNTRY>XF</PERMADDCOUNTRY>
        <PERMADDPOSTCODE>N17 9HQ</PERMADDPOSTCODE>
      </EntryProfile>
      <Leaver>
        <ENGENDDATE>2022-12-16</ENGENDDATE>
        <RSNENGEND>11</RSNENGEND>
      </Leaver>
      <StudentCourseSession>
        <SCSESSIONID>A220926DET</SCSESSIONID>
        <COURSEID>DET</COURSEID>
        <INVOICEFEEAMOUNT>6000</INVOICEFEEAMOUNT>
        <RSNSCSEND>01</RSNSCSEND>
        <SCSENDDATE>2022-12-16</SCSENDDATE>
        <SCSEXPECTEDENDDATE>2023-06-23</SCSEXPECTEDENDDATE>
        <SCSMODE>01</SCSMODE>
        <SCSSTARTDATE>2022-09-26</SCSSTARTDATE>
        <SESSIONYEARID>A220926DET</SESSIONYEARID>
        <YEARPRG>1</YEARPRG>
        <ReferencePeriodStudentLoad>
          <REFPERIOD>01</REFPERIOD>
          <YEAR>2022</YEAR>
          <RPSTULOAD>100</RPSTULOAD>
        </ReferencePeriodStudentLoad>
        <StudyLocation>
          <STUDYLOCID>A</STUDYLOCID>
          <STUDYPROPORTION>100</STUDYPROPORTION>
          <VENUEID>A</VENUEID>
        </StudyLocation>
      </StudentCourseSession>
    </Engagement>
  </Student>
</datafutures>
```

I tried the usual process of importing xml but the first record is repeating 18 times while 2nd is 16 times. I am attaching a screen shot
and I f export to create XML then I get the message "Can not save or export XML data, XML map in this file are not exportable"

Answer (score 0):

please find the missing screen shot here
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFtZT.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).